# localStorage fallback attempt on file:// protocol

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, offline, fallback

I am working on an offline website that based on `js` and `html` (of course), so it's being served via the `file:// protocol`.

In the website there's an option to mark items and add them to a list (like a "cart"). If it was an online version - I would use cookies and ajax/php. Since I can't use cookies (HTTP protocol), I found the `localStorage` object which fits to my requirements.

However, it seems that `localStorage` isn't really working on IE with file:// protocol, while on Chrome it does. (Like there aren't enough reasons to hate IE). And this is where my journey for localStorage alternative/fallback begin.

My fallback is to use the `window.name` to [store data](http://www.sitepoint.com/cookieless-javascript-session-variables/).

My code:

```
//Modernizr approach - is localStorage being supported?
function supportLocalStorage(){
    var test = 'test';
    try {
        localStorage.setItem(test, test);
        localStorage.removeItem(test);
        return true;
    } catch(e) {
        return false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(supportLocalStorage() !== true){
        alert("boo"); 
        var localStorage = {
            getItem: function (key) {
                if(window.name == null || window.name == "")
                    return "{}"; //Later i'm about to use JSON Parser.
                return window.name;
            },
            setItem: function (key, val) {
                window.name = val;
            }
        }

    }

    var products_list = localStorage.getItem("products");
}
```

But now it seems that on IE everything is ok (no error), but on Chrome it gives the following error: (relates to the `var products_list` line)

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined

And if I remove the class declaration code-block of `localStorage = {..` it works again on Chrome but not on IE. Why does it happen? Am I missing something?

Any suggestion/tip/help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `localStorage` var declared inside `if` is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) to the top of the function and it [shadowed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the global `localStorage` variable.

One solution to this may be setting local `localStorage` to global value at the top:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var localStorage = window.localStorage;
    if(supportLocalStorage() !== true){
        alert("boo"); 
        localStorage = {
            getItem: function (key) {
                if(window.name == null || window.name == "")
                    return "{}"; //Later i'm about to use JSON Parser.
                return window.name;
            },
            setItem: function (key, val) {
                window.name = val;
            }
        }

    }

    var products_list = localStorage.getItem("products");
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed the `hoisted` effect. Thanks a lot.